# dynamic order of html table header

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

What is the best way to dynamically build html table header? I have a List of objects which describes the order table header should be.

```
public final class Header {
    private final Long id;         // Unique id of the header
    private final String label;    // Printed in the table header area
    private final Boolean enabled; // If this header is enabled or not
    private final Short position;   // The position in the header i.e 1, 2, 3, etc

    // Constructor, and getters. This is a value object so there are no setters. 
}
```

I would like to pass to my template system (java thymeleaf) a List and loop through the list to build the table structure. I am also using spring mvc.

Any help would be very nice :-). Please let me know if any other information is needed. Below is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <!-- Loop through the List<Header> -->
        <tr>
            <th th:each="header : ${headers}">
                th:text="${header.label}"
            </th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to take array of headers

```
String headers[] = {"a","b","c","d"}
out.println("<table><tr>");

for(i=0;i<headers.length();i++)
{
   out.print("<th>" + headers[i] + "</th>");
}
out.println("</tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (use a span-tag within th):

```
<tr>
<th th:each="header: ${headers}">
<span th:text="${header.label}"></span>
</th>
</tr>
```